# Android, EditText preservation through new activities

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I preserve data between activities? For instance, I have an edit text and a button in Activity A. I fill in that editText and then click on the button. That button starts a new intent, Activity B. In B there are several buttons, but all of them if clicked on, start activity A again. I want that editText to be still filled in as well as pass specific data to Activity A depending on the button pressed in Activity B.
I know this has to do with onStop() -> onStart(), but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start Activity B with **[startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))**. Then, when u set the result, you should "catch" it in Activity A by overriding `onActivityResult()`.

As for EditText, if you don't call finish() on Activity A - you don't need to override `onSaveInstanceState` or anything else - system does it for you.

Comment: It doesn't save the EditText for me, I never called finish, but when I go to Activity A from B, the text is gone. I'm not simply going back when I'm in Activity B, I end up making a new intent to go to Activity A and starting that intent. Is there some way to just start the previous intent? Is that what startActivityForResult does?

Comment: You start new instance of Activity A, of course EditText will be clear. You should use startActivityForResult in Activity A, and setResult() and then finish() in Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish the activity in Activity A intent to Activity B. and use `startActivityForResult(intent)` rather than `startActivity(intent)` to be able to pass the data back to activity A again. check this answer to how [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android).